# How to suppress or skip TypeScript error for specific plugin

Tags: jquery, typescript, visual-studio-2015, datatables, typescript-typings

I am using jQuery DataTable (latest version) in my ASP.NET WebForm project. While using jQuery DataTable in my TypeScript file, I am getting error for missing typings in the jquery.dataTables.d.ts file. Please see the error below,

[image]

Eventhough the syntax is correct, because of the missing typings, I am getting error.

For example, the following is a valid code, but, it throws missing typing error in a typescript file.

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    scrollY: true,
    scroller: {
        loadingIndicator: true
    }
} );
```

**Question:**

Is there any way to suppress or omit only the jQuery datatable related error in my TypeScript file(s)?

I am using jQuery, Bootstrap and other plugins in my project and if there is any missing typings in them, I want to see the error. But, only for jQuery datatable, I want to suppress the error.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: you're probably better off adding the typing for DataTable.